# Building a VS2015 x64 project using glew 1.13.0 and CMake 3.4.0

Tags: cmake, glew

How do I build a VS2015 x64 project using glew 1.13.0 and CMake 3.4.0?

I prepared a minimal demo that can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/cmakedemos/src/2fbbc02b2c0567319d7be070b34391b1ef35048d/GlewDemo/?at=default

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8)
project ( GlewDemo )

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

set ( SRCS main.cpp )

add_executable(GlewDemo ${SRCS})

target_link_libraries(GlewDemo glew32s)
```

I downloaded the prebuilt binaries from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.13.0/glew-1.13.0-win32.zip/download

And set the path of GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR to the corresponding directory ("C:\Users\no68koc\Downloads\glew-1.13.0\include")

But CMake gives me some errors:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:44 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/build/vs2015/GlewDemo/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How does it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake cannot locate your GLEW. Thus you have to hint CMake.

Either include GLEW to some place, where CMake looks for components. Installing GLEW comes to mind.

Or you define the variables manually. You already did that for `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR`. You have to define `GLEW_LIBRARY`, too.
It must be the path to the library named glew32, glew, or glew32s. With Unices it should be lib*.so maybe with some additional version numbers. With Windows it should be *.dll or *.lib.

Comment: Is it possible to set only the "root" directory (e.g. "C:\Users\no68koc\Downloads\glew-1.13.0") of glew - and everything else works automatically? It seems that the FindGlew.cmake file provided by CMake is very cumbersome to use. Maybe because of this several people started to write thier own FindGlew.cmake files such as here: https://github.com/tlorach/OpenGLText/blob/master/cmake/FindGLEW.cmake

Comment: No, it's not. I just checked the source code of FindGLEW.cmake. Probably one could improve the test provided by CMake. But the one you linked looks broken, too. Why should one mark FOUND_GLEW as advanced?

Comment: I guess nobody is maintaining the module anymore. Open a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

Error message

```
Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_LIBRARY)
```

is a standard message generated by `FindXXX.cmake` script (called via `find_package(XXX)`), that it is failed to set(deduce) some CMake variables, so **whole package is assumed to be not found**.

Most of FindXXX.cmake scripts descibes(in the comment), which variables are set by the script **for user**.

But only several of them describes, **how user can help script** in case when the script failed to find needed package at all, or if user wants script to find specific package installation instead of default one.

There is no universal approach in helping to the `FindXXX.cmake` script, in most cases one should analize code of the script for know variables, which can help.

In the given case (with `GLEW` package) analizing CMake-provided [FindGLEW.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake) script reveals, that both `find_path()` call (which set `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR` variable) and `find_library()` call (which set `GLEW_LIBRARY` variable) use no hints (HINT or PATH options) for search. But there are standard hints, which are used by both of this commands. One of these hints is `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/include` directory for [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_path.html) and similar directory for [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_library.html).

So you can use

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\Users\no68koc\Downloads\glew-1.13.0")
```

for hint to find_library() and find_path() to search under this directory too.
Alternatively, you may set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable in CMake cache either in GUI (e.g. inside Visual Studio) or via command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=C:\Users\no68koc\Downloads\glew-1.13.0
```

(Note, that using `list(APPEND ...)` instead of `set(...)` within `CMakeLists.txt` does not override variable in case it is set in cache too).

---

**You may use another, 3d-party [FindGLEW.cmake](https://github.com/tlorach/OpenGLText/blob/master/cmake/FindGLEW.cmake) script**

You can download it into your project (e.g., to `cmake/FindGLEW.cmake`) and issue

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
```

for tell `find_package()` to use this script instead of default one.

Given script uses

```
${GLEW_LOCATION}
```

directory (and its subdirectories) as hint for searching in `find_path()` and `find_library()` (under PATH command's option). So you can set `GLEW_LOCATION` variable to installation directory:

```
set(GLEW_LOCATION "C:\Users\no68koc\Downloads\glew-1.13.0")
```

for make things work. Alternatively(and preferrably), this variable can be set in cache.

Also, given `FindGLEW.cmake` script uses

```
$ENV{GLEW_LOCATION}
```

directory as hint. This means that setting `GLEW_LOCATION` *environment variable* will also helps.